# Agile Web Development with Rails 4 ActionView::Template: undefined local variable or method `products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. I am a Ruby Newbie and I am following the Book Agile Development with Rails 4, page 95
2. I created a second store controller and get the following error: undefined local variable or method `products'. Somebody knows what is missing?

View

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry">
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
  <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
  <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
  <div class="price_line">
    <span class="price"><%= products.price %></span>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>



class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
  end
end


.store {

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            font: 150% sans-serif;
            color: #226;
            border-bottom: 3px dotted #77d;
        }

        /* And entry in the store catalog */
        .entry {
            overflow: auto;
            margin-top: 1em;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted 77d;
            min-height: 100px

        img {
            with: 80px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 120%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            color: #227;
        }

        p, div.price_line {
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            margin-bottom: 0.8em;

        }

        .price {
            color: *44a;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 3em;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="price"><%= products.price %></span>
```

should be

```
<span class="price"><%= product.price %></span>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for you hint. I corrected the error, but if I start the server the error notification still remains: No it says: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: No, it is working, I saved every page again. Thanks Ian!